# MKAnnotationView update title and subtitle with distance when event is received

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mapkit, mkpinannotationview, mkannotationview

I'm developing an iphone app using mapkit and CLLocationManager.

I put lots of MKPinAnnotationView on map (about 100) and I want to update all callout's subtitle  whith user distance when I receive it.

How to do it ?

Thanks

---

I try this to update subtitle callout with new location but it didn't work well.

In my MyAppDelegate.h

```
extern NSString * const GMAP_USERLOCATION_CHANGED; 

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *userLocation;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *userLocation;
@end
```

In my MyAppDelegate.m

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

NSString * const GMAP_USERLOCATION_CHANGED = @"gMapUserLocationChanged"; 
@synthesize locationManager, userLocation;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    userLocation = nil;
    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Core Location delegate
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager 
{
    if (locationManager != nil) 
 {
        return locationManager;
    }

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    return locationManager; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
                   fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
 self.userLocation = newLocation;
 // send notification to defaulcenter
 NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [nc postNotificationName:GMAP_USERLOCATION_CHANGED object:self.userLocation];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [locationManager release];
    [userLocation release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I made a customAnnotationView named MyAnnotation.

in MyAnnotation.h :

```
@interface MyAnnotation : MKPinAnnotationView<MKAnnotation>
{
 double longitude;
 double latitude;
 NSString *title;
 NSString *subtitle;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subtitle;
@property double longitude;
@property double latitude;
@end
```

in MyAnnotation.m :

```
#import "MyAnnotation.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

@synthesize title, subtitle;
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize latitude;

-(id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
 self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
 if (self != nil) 
 {
  NSLog(@"add observer");
  NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNewUserLocation:) name:GMAP_USERLOCATION_CHANGED object:nil];
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)setTitleAndSubtitle 
{
 [self setTitleAndSubtitle:nil];
}

- (id)setTitleAndSubtitle:(CLLocation*)userLocation
{
 CLLocationDistance dist = -1;

 if(userLocation)
 {
  CLLocation *poiLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.latitude longitude:self.longitude];
  dist = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:poiLoc] / 1000;
  NSLog(@"distance is now %.f", dist);
 }

 title = @"the Title of the poi!";

 subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %@", 
    dist > -1 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", dist] : @"-"
    ];

 return self;
}

- (void)receivedNewUserLocation:(NSNotification *)userLocationNotification
{
 CLLocation *userlocation = (CLLocation*)[userLocationNotification object];
 [self setTitleAndSubtitle:userlocation];
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = latitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = longitude;
    return theCoordinate; 
}

- (NSString *)title
{
    return title;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return subtitle;
}

- (void)dealloc
{ 
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

In the end I use it like that in my MapViewController (I put only the viewForAnnotation delegate method here):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MyAnnotation *annotationView = nil;
    MyAnnotation* myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;
    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    NSString* identifier = @"CustomMapAnnotation";
    MyAnnotation *customPinView = (MyAnnotation *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];


    if(nil == customPinView) 
    {
 // if an existing pin view was not available, create one
 customPinView = [[[MyAnnotation alloc]
    initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation 
    reuseIdentifier:identifier] 
    autorelease];

 customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
 customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }

    annotationView = customPinView;
    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return annotationView;
}
```

After all of this subtitle is not update after the mkannotation is load on map....
What's wrong ?

thanks for your help...

Answer (score 6):

When you update the title, you should notify the MKAnnotationView to update the callout view, by whichever KVO manner that fits your need best, e.g.:

1. synthesize or implement setter for title and use

   ```
   self.title = @"new title";
   ```
2. use explicit KVO notifications

   ```
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
   [title release];
   title = [newTitle copy];
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
   ```

Ditto for subtitle.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are creating your MKAnnotations.

You should probably have an object like "Place" represented by Place.h and Place.m, which conform to the MKAnnotation protocol...

Place would have a property along the lines of

```
float distance;
```

Then your subtitle method (part of MKAnnotation) would do something like this

```
- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f Miles Away", distance];
}
```

That subtitle method gets called by the mapview constantly (in fact its almost ridiculous how often it gets called), so as soon as you manipulate the value of distance, it will be reflected on the map (perhaps as early as the next time you tap on the pin).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It seems it's a nice solution. I wanted before of that to try to read annotations array in my mapviewcontroller when I received a position update with CLLocationManager. But the title was unreachable.

About the refresh time I though about to add the CLLocationManager into appdelegate which will change a property of it and then monitor this property with an observer to change the location each time I receive an update. I will see if it work. If it's the case i'll post the solution here...

Comment: i think there is something else missing.  Yes this will return the distance in the subtitle of each annotation, but you must set the distance somewhere else.